# Saving Image file in same directory with different filename

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to save the image file in same folder but I have to make a new directory in my 'test' folder every time and it save one image per folder. I need to make single directory so that i can save my multiple image files with different filename.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog 
from tkinter.ttk import *
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfile

def watermark(file ,water_mark_text):
image = Image.open(file).convert("RGBA")
txt = Image.new('RGBA', image.size, (255,255,255,0))


image_width,image_height =image.size

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(txt)
# It is done to increase the font sizeof text  with image if it will be fixed number like 50 then for high resolution image it will appear small
font_size=int(image_width/4)


font=ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf',font_size)
# add watermark
draw.text((int(image_width/2), int(image_height/1.5)),water_mark_text ,fill=(0,0,0,50), stroke_fill="#222",anchor='mb',
           font=font)
combined = Image.alpha_composite(image, txt)

# to show the image
combined.show()
image_path = 'C:/Users/user/Pictures/test/two'
os.mkdir(image_path)

res=combined.save(f"{image_path}/image.png")


def open_file():
file=filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='Users\user') 
watermark(file,"XYZ")


window=Tk()
window.title("APP")
window.geometry('300x200')

lable=Label(text="Select the image",font=("Arial", 25))
lable.pack()
lable.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.3, anchor=CENTER)
Button1=Button(text="select image",command=open_file)
Button1.pack()
Button1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I wonder what your issue is because you already know how to create folder and save the image.  Also I have comment in your other question that you need to call either `.pack()` or `.place()` on same widget, not both because the later will override the former.

Comment: Hi, actually i can save the file but i need to change the name every time of code is run. In order to do that the name needs to be saved as a variable otherwise it will overlap.

Comment: Simply use current timestamp as part of the image filename, then it should be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have different filename for the image, one of the way is to add the current timestamp as part of the filename:

```py
from datetime import datetime
...

def watermark(file, water_mark_text):
    ...
    timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    res = combined.save(f"{image_path}/image.{timestamp}.png")

...
```